# java generic objects how to store in data structure

Tags: java, generics

the code I have is:

```
interfacebase<T>

interfaceA extends interface<A>  ---> interfaceAImpl implements interfaceA 
interfaceB extends interface<B>  ---> interfaceBImpl implements interfaceB


interfaceA  AObj = interfaceAImpl()
interfaceB  BObj = interfaceBImpl()
```

my question is : can java store AObj and BObj in a List or a Map ?
if java can, then how to achieve that

Comment: May be OP is interested in generics parameters for that List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, without loosing all type information.

```
List<interfacebase<?>> list = new ArrayList<interfacebase<?>>();
list.add(AObj);
list.add(BObj);
```

Comment: actually my case is :
there is a method call_Method_(T Tobj) :
 I need to call like this---> list.get(0).call_Method_(Aobj);
but i cannot, so i need to change the structure to set a baseclass for  A and B?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `ArrayList<Object>` or `HashMap<Object>` you can put inside them whatever you want.
If you have a defined base class/interface called `BASE` and you would like to store some objects coming from it's derived class called `DERIVED`, you should change `Object` to `BASE`.
In this case you can store every kind of object into your list/map, which is derived from BASE, or implements it (in case of interface): `ArrayList<BASE>`, `HashMap<BASE>`.